# Python - How can I re-prompt for different input before continuing code

Tags: python, if-statement, input

I'm making a turn-based text combat system, and I'm trying to add "cool downs" to certain abilities.

I've done this, but even if an ability is on cool down and the the user presses the button for the spell, the turn still gets consumed and the spell doesn't work.

I can add an except value error to something that's not an available option, but I'm struggling to add it to something that can sometimes be an option.

```
ab1 = 1 #This is tracker for cool down (if its 0 the spell can be used)
if(ab1 == 0):
   print("1)",ability1)
else:
    print("1)",ability1, "- This ability is not ready")
useSpell = input("")
if(useSpell == "1") and (ab1 == 0):
    #Do Spell Stuff
else:
    #This is where I believe I need to block the code from continuing
```

There are **3 spells** so it looks something like this when printed:

Choose an ability.

1) Spell name - Ability is not ready yet (assuming this spell is on cool down)

2) Spell name

3) Spell name

How do I stop the code from continuing and reprompt the user to choose another number if the spell they choose is unavailable.
(I have already blocked the spell from working just not the turn for a new input)

Answer (score 2):

***How do I stop the code from continuing and re prompt the user to
choose another if the spell they choose is unavailable?***

If the user chooses a spell that's unavailable, just use a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop to re-prompt the user for another spell:

```
ab1 = 1 #This is tracker for cool down (if its 0 the spell can be used)
if(ab1 == 0):
   print("1)",ability1)
else:
    print("1)",ability1, "- This ability is not ready")

while True:           
    if(input("") == "1") and (ab1 == 0):
        #Do Spell Stuff
        break;    #Add a break statement when an available spell is inputted
#   else:
#       ab1=0
```

Just remember, you'd have to watch the value of `ab1` inside the loop (change it from 1 to 0, or else you'd end up with an infinite while-loop).

There are many different ways you could implement a while-loop in your code, but loops are what most people use to re-prompt the user for inputs.